# What's the "Find Result" Control Visual Studio Integrated?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, controls, textbox, double-click

I am developing a simple Windows Application in C# and Visual Studio 2005.
I need a search result control - just like visual studio integrated by itself. After I double click each line to trigger the individual event.  I tried multi-line `textBox Control`, but whole the box can only support one click event. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a ListBox instead of a TextBox control.